# Match , space and [A-z] with possible second comma RegEx

Tags: ruby, regex, rename

I have files named

```
Author_1999.pdf
Authorone, Authortwo_1999.pdf
Authorone, Authortwo, Authorthree.pdf   
Arian, Nachmias, Amir_2002.pdf
Author, Review, Source_2015(2).pdf
Avraham, Hacohen_1930.pdf
```

that were produced by reference manager Mendeley.  I need them all in the format of Authorone1999.pdf  or  Authorone1999(2).pdf.  I have regex that only matches the last comma space author and _

```
/(, )+[A-z ]*,?[A-z]*,?-?[A-z]*_/
```

[image]

How can I match on the optional first comma space Authortwo as well.  There are never more than two commas because that produced

```
Authorone, et al._1999.pdf
```

and I've already cleaned those up.

Comment: `Authorone, Authortwo, Authorthree.pdf` doesn't even have a year. How to handle this?

Comment: Since there is no "_" at the end of [A-z] to delete I don't want it to be matched.  There are only a few like this and I'll have to do them by hand.  Match only files with ending year `files = Dir['*'].select {|x| x =~ /d*.pdf/}`

Comment: Do not use regexr, use [rubular](http://rubular.com) to test Ruby regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
/^(?<author>[a-z-]+).*_(?<year>[\d()]+)/i
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/GCxn2uHNTg)

This will store the `author` and `year` into two named capture groups.

Comment: What about `-` in author's name? and multiple authors comma separated?

Comment: Ah, I missed the hyphens, sorry - there were none in the example text (but there is in the image). That's trivial to fix -- edited.

Comment: As for multiple authors, to be honest I'm not clear what the OP actually wants. Should `Arian, Nachmias, Amir_2002.pdf` be converted to `ArianNachmiasAmir2002.pdf`? Or, three files named `Arian2002.pdf`, `Nachmias2002.pdf` and `Amir2002.pdf`? Or are we just taking the first author's name, as I have done here? The examples given are unclear.

Comment: Tom I was just matching after the comma in this question. Was going to handle the rename separately. Amir2002.pdf is the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/, +[A-Za-z-]+(?:, [A-Za-z-]+)?(?:, [A-Za-z-]+)?_/
```